# Backup software which allows to synchronize individual registry entries between two computers

Tags: backup, windows-registry

Does anyone know any backup software which, in addition to synchronizing files, also allows parts of the registry to be synchronized?

I would like to keep several applications settings synchronized across two computers, and to do that I need to also synchronize individual registry entries.

I know I can manually create a .bat file which exports the keys I want to synchronize and then import those into the computer I'll be working, but I was wondering if there's any software which would automate this.

Comment: Could've sworn there was a similar question on the same topic, can't find it now